# How to write condition based on expression?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to write condition based on expression.
I have two classes Test1 and Test2.

```cs
public class Test1<TEntity, TProperty>
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Test(
        IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression,
        TProperty value
    )
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)(expression.Body);
        var propName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        // Cannot apply operator '>' to operands of type 'P' and 'P'
        queryable = queryable.Where(e => EF.Property<TProperty>(e, propName) > value));
        return queryable;
    }
}

public class Test2<TEntity, TProperty>
    where TProperty : IComparable
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Test(
        IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression,
        TProperty value
    )
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)(expression.Body);
        var propName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        // This one compiles
        queryable = queryable.Where(e => EF.Property<TProperty>(e, propName).CompareTo(value) > 0);
        return queryable;
    }
}
```

First one (Test1) tries to compare values with `>` but it does not compile. Second one (Test2) declares generic type as IComparable and uses .CompareTo() method inside where condition. This one compiles but on runtime it throws:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SortableEntity>
    .Where(s => s.IsDeleted == False)
    .Where(s => EF.Property<long>((object)s, "Id").CompareTo((object)__value_0) > 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

Is it possible to somehow write custom condition based on expression? I want property/member expression to be passed by user and then decide what condition to apply to IQueryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `EF.Property` is last thing that you have to use in such situation. You have property, even correct body - use this:

```cs
public class Test1<TEntity, TProperty>
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Test(
        IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression,
        TProperty value
    )
    {
        var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.GreaterThan(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TProperty))), 
            expression.Parameters[0]);

        queryable = queryable.Where(predicateLambda);
        return queryable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code for some reason fails to compile: getting "Cannot resolve method 'GreaterThan(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression, System.Type)', candidates are: ..."

Comment: Fixed, writing from memory and made mistake with brackets.

Comment: Thanks, it works even without `typeof(TProperty)` at all. Just `Expression.GreaterThan(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(value))`.

Comment: Yes, `Expression.Constant` can get type from value, if it is not null. But better to pass this information if it is exists.